# Error occured while trying to proxy on angular 4 rpoject, URL configured for HTTPS

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I've been trying to hit angular 4 project, deployed locally on my machine on port 4200 using a HTML page's form :-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <form action="https://test-pubg.sohum.com:4200" target="_blank" method="post">
    Access: <input type="text" id="accessToken" name="accessToken"><br> Refresh: <input type="text" id="refreshToken" name="refreshToken"><br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button><br>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

But i'm getting

> *Error occured while trying to proxy to: test-pubg.sohum.com:4200/*

on the browser.

I've configured the route configuration for ***https*** in package.json which is as follows:

```
"start": "ng serve --disable-host-check --ssl 1 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --host 0.0.0.0",
```

My proxy settings in proxy.conf.json are as follows :-

```js
{
    "/**": {
        "target": {
            "host": "test-pubg.sohum.com",
            "port": 8080,
            "protocol": "http:"
        },
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

I've already tried all the possible solutions available on other similar threads on github & stackoverflow. But nothing has worked till now.

I'm new to angular & have already spent days on it. Any possible solution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your problem is, but I'm usually not splitting the `target` configuration as distinct host, port and protocol. I'm just using `"target": "http://localhost:18080"` in my proxy config. Did you try this ? Another point : As I'm always proxying more than one path, I never used the `"/**"` path matcher. Can you try to use `/test-pubg/` in your form and use `"/test-pubg/"` in your proxy config ?

Comment: @Wis Thanks for responding. I've already tried with your suggested changes but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after spending a lot of time what i found it was related to architectural issue. First, try understand to the architecture :-
HTML(on some different server) -> angular(HTTPS) -> spring boot

so problem was Angular was trying to hit from HTTPS angular to NON-HTTP Spring boot. SO as solution i configured HTTPS for spring boot & Voila!! it worked.